# Azure Relay Hybridconnection Request Response Integrity

Tags: azure, azure-hybrid-connections

As an attempt to improve performance, Im proposing to use one common hybrid connection for all user's requests for on premises resource, in this case how to ensure the response received from hybridconnection is for the request sent since all user's request/response passes through common connection. Please advice.